# Creating one instance of a flaskwebgui flask app using a lock file

Tags: python, flask

Hi I have a small web app I'm developing using python and flask. The app works fine and I've updated it to use the flaskwebgui library so it opens as its own app instead of the browser. My question is in regards to how to allow it to only be opened once and while opened not be opened again until the initial instance is closed. Essentially having only one instance of the app open at once.

I have the following code.

```
lock_file_path = "app_file_lock.lock"

def create_lock_file():
    with open(lock_file_path, "w") as lock_file:
         lock_file.write(f"Locked, OS PID: {os.getpid()}")
            
def remove_lock_file():
    if os.path.exists(lock_file_path):
          os.remove(lock_file_path)
```

In my main function I have the following.

```
if os.path.exists(lock_file_path):
   print(f"Another Instance of the App is running")
else:
   create_lock_file()
   ui = FlaskUI(app=app, server="flask", width=1024, height=768).run()
   #remove_log_file()
   atexit.register(remove_lock_file)
```

As shown I've tried just calling the remove_log_file() directly but that has not worked. I've added the atexit library and that has not worked. I've also tried FlaskUI's on_shutdown call and still does not work (that in fact causes the app to error out). Been wrestling with this for a couple of days so just hoping a second set of eyes will be able to help. Thanks in advance.